# Compiles in Eclipse but doesn't compile in windows command prompt

Tags: java, windows, compiler-errors

A program I wrote, `RandomStrings` makes use of a static method,`getRandomLowerCaseCharacter()` in another class, `GeneratingRandomCharacters`. The code compiles and executes without any issues in Eclipse, but in windows command prompt it won't successfully compile.

This is the error I get when compiling in windows command prompt

[image]

The issue occurs where I access the `GeneratingRandomCharacters` class from within the class I'm trying to compile, `RandomStrings`.

What is causing this compile error?

Comment: I'm guessing that the class with the static method is not in your build path when you try and compile it on the command prompt. I can't see your image with the error. I'm not sure if it's just me but paste it here if you can.

Comment: Eclipse does much more than a simple `javac RandomStrings.java`. You should look into the classpath and managing packages.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it was the classpath, you're right. I appreciate your help. You should add it as an answer, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "**GeneratingRandomCharacters**" is placed in the same folder where "**RandomStrings**" is placed.

Also, make sure "**getRandomLowerCaseCharacter()**" method returns the same "type" of value that "**randomString**" is. Or, otherwise use explicit type casting to convert it into that type as:

randomString += (**Type of value**)GeneratingRandomCharacters.getRandomLowerCaseCharacter();

Comment: They are in the same folder. The code compiles and runs in Eclipse, so I don't think the issue is with casting. But, in reply to that, I'm concatenating a `String` with a `char`, which results in a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the other java file in the command.

```
javac RandomStrings.java RandomCharacters.java
```

Replacing RandomCharacters.java with whatever the other file is called. I believe Eclipse takes care of including dependencies in compilation, rather than the base compiler.